# How to handle long paths using std::filesystem in c++17

Tags: boost, windows-10, c++17, boost-filesystem, std-filesystem

On Windows I am trying to iterate and collect all the files in the directory, Also I want to handle long paths and thats why I've added long path prefix (L"\\?\"). but it crashes with c++17's std::filesystem. Also I've tried the same with boost::filesystem and It also crashed, However If I don't add the prefix, it works. I want this code to work on mostly on any version of windows-10/11. How do I handle the possibility of encountering long path.

```
    void IterateDir(const std::string& newDir)
    {
        namespace fs = std::filesystem;
    
        fs::path rootPath;
        std::wstring wpath(newDir.begin(), newDir.end());
        wpath = std::wstring(L"\\\\?\\") + wpath;
        rootPath.assign(wpath);
    
        for (auto iter = fs::recursive_directory_iterator(rootPath);
            iter != fs::recursive_directory_iterator();
            ++iter) {
            try {
                auto file = *iter;
                std::string filename = file.path().filename().string();
                std::cout << "\nfile: " << filename;
            }
            catch (const std::exception& e) {
                std::cout << "Exception while iterating directory." + std::string(e.what());
            }
            catch (...) {
                std::cout << "Unknown exception while iterating directory.";
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

What I've found that, There is a known issue with the C++ 17 filesystem crashing when iterating a directory with a long path prefix in wstring. The issue is caused by the way the filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator handles the files. When the iterator reaches a file with Unicode characters, it crashes.

Comment: They're not file paths but NT Object Manager paths. It will not work, but should not "crash". If you see a crash than without a doubt you answered your own question: _"The issue is caused by the way the `filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` handles the files. When the iterator reaches a file with Unicode characters, it crashes"_? What else is there to ask?

Comment: By the way, you can easily simplify your code and improve it a lot (at least protecting against permission error) https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee9080bb2952231b, of course that's running on Linux so I cannot reproduce a crash

Comment: Thanks @sehe Now I have better understanding if it. I am using boost::filesystem and its working fine.

Comment: Hmm? In your question you said "Also I've tried the same with boost::filesystem and It also crashed" - If my code snippet helped then (a) it's not a crash (b) there may have been permission issues (c) let me post an answer :)

Comment: Yes Please! u can post answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Object Manager Paths will not work with either `std::filesystem` or `boost::filesystem` (you need platform specific API like `NtOpenDirectoryObject`, `NtQueryDirectoryObject`).

That said, neither library ought to crash. Barring bugs (which are unlikely, and if they bite you, you can probably upgrade the library to fix it), you might simply be running into permission errors which will cause runtime exceptions to be raised.

So, here's a version that simplifies the code while adding minimal precautions to deal with permission problems during traversal:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee9080bb2952231b)**

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void IterateDir(fs::path dir, char const* nsPrefix = R"(\\?\)") {
    auto flags = fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied;
    for (auto&& entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(nsPrefix / dir, flags)) {
        try {
            std::cout << "file: " << entry.path().filename() << "\n";
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cout << "Exception while iterating directory." + std::string(e.what()) << "\n";
        } catch (...) {
            std::cout << "Unknown exception while iterating directory.\n";
        }
    }
}

int main() { 
    IterateDir(".", ""); 
    IterateDir("."); 
}
```

You can see the first iterate works:

```
file: "main.cpp"
file: "a.out"
```

The second one raises an exception (that goes unhandled, leading to program termination):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: recursive directory iterator cannot open directory: No such file or directory [\\?\/.]
```

On windows you might get different behaviour, but a crash should never happen.

### BONUS

Boost version **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbc385d1a5cd18d4)**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
```

showing the same output except the exception is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem::filesystem_error'
  what():  boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: No such file or directory [system:2]: "\\?\/."
```

Comment: Thank you so much @sehe, This resolved my problem. but this prefix is only working with boost::filesystem (v1800), not with std::filesystem, using which iterator still crashes just when encounters long path, with exception "recursive_directory_iterator::operator++: The system cannot find the path specified."(built on Visual Studio 2019, toolset v142, c++17).
what should be done to get std::filesystem to support long path. I was under impression that std::filesystem supports this out of the box. Earlier, I was using std::experimental::filesystem (c++14) which was working with this prefix.

Comment: Thanks for the report (and addition about boost v1800+). Again, throwing an exception is not "crashing", just so you know you can avoid a bit of confusion in the future. `std::experimental::filesystem` may have been Microsoft's implementation from before it was even proposed for standardization? I do remember MSVC was the very first compiler to support `std::filesystem` back when, so that might explain.

Comment: Could you please point me in the right direction, where I could find some closure on this whole std::filesystem not working with this prefix, or should I update my build environment to VS2023, C++20?

Comment: What is left to ask? I explained how the behaviour will never be standard (because non-portable) and the answer already describes how to list the special windows object namespaces

Comment: Got it now, thanks!